# Tint an Image Universal app

Tags: win-universal-app, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Is it possible to tint an image a certain color(Universal App)?. WinRTXamltoolkit sounds promising (ColorExtensions). There is zero documentation tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use `ColorExtensions` to add a hue overlay to your image, but that runs on a CPU and a pixel shader would be a much better choice. I'm not sure what [Lumia Imaging SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598502.aspx) uses, but it sounds like it might have everything you need.